# Accessing props after destructuring arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component. It has access to React-router props like Match, History, Location. But it also has access to articles prop. When I destructure articles, all the props disappear. When I console.log I get an empty object with no Match, History etc. How can you destructure while keeping props? I know I can destructure Match and History as well. But I want props.

```
//component
<Home articles={articles} />

//component
const Home = ({articles}, ...props) => {
console.log(props)
console.log(...props)
...coding stuff here....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the curly brace location.

```
//component
<Home articles={articles} />

//component
const Home = ({articles, ...props}) => {
console.log(props)
console.log(...props)
...coding stuff here....
}
```

Comment: LOL, that was... anticlimactic. Thank you though :-)

Answer (score 0):

i think , you dont even have to use `articles` , see this

```
//component
<Home articles={articles} />

//component
const Home = ({...props}) => {
console.log(props)
console.log(...props)
...coding stuff here....
}
```